# .net mvc updated - namespaces not recognized in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, web-config

I updated some project files like jQuery, added Bootstrap. I just clicked Update all in my project through packager.

Now I checked my web.config and some namespaces are not recognized:
[image]

Which makes another stuff on website non recognizable:
[image]

Page works normal though. What can I do here?

Comment: Do you use ReSharper?

Comment: Yes I do use ReSharper.

Comment: Just curious if you tried recycling VS?

Comment: What is recycling VS?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by ReSharper. Try clearing the cache  : ReSharper -> Options -> General -> Clear Cache and restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you actually don't have reference to mvc libs or just bug of resharper